# Cannot ORDER BY when querying Custom Metadata

Tags: soql, custom-metadata, metadata-relationship

I have Custom Metadata types with simple relationships between them. When I query them with a relationship query and try to ORDER BY, only 1 of the inner records is returned.

I run this in Anonymous Apex:

```
Id tmp = ''; // This is populated, I'm just not putting it here
List<Parent__mdt> tmpList = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel, Custom_Order__c, Super__c,
                             (SELECT Id, MasterLabel, Custom_Order__c,
                              FROM Childs__r) 
                             FROM Parent__mdt 
                             WHERE Super__c = :tmp 
                             ORDER BY Custom_Order__c ASC NULLS FIRST];

System.debug(tmpList[0].Childs__r.size());
```

...and I correctly see that there are 36 'Child' metadata records within that Parent. However, running the same code with an ORDER BY in the relationship clause:

```
Id tmp = ''; // Again, this is populated
List<Parent__mdt> tmpList = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel, Custom_Order__c, Super__c,
                             (SELECT Id, MasterLabel, Custom_Order__c,
                              FROM Childs__r
                              ORDER BY Custom_Order__c) 
                             FROM Parent__mdt 
                             WHERE Super__c = :tmp 
                             ORDER BY Custom_Order__c ASC NULLS FIRST];

System.debug(tmpList[0].Childs__r.size());
```

...returns only 1 'Child' within the Parent.

Is this documented anywhere? Is there a way around this?

Comment: There have been a number of known issues this release regarding querying custom metadata... You may want to log a bug with Support.

Comment: the workaround would be to use a custom apex type that implemented Comparable interface and sort the children in code

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for the heads-up, I'll log with support when I get the chance.

Comment: @cropredy Thanks for pointing me toward the comparable interface, that's going to make things a lot smoother.

Answer (score 1):

You can order by with only non-relationship fields for custom meta datatype as per documentation. [Documentation link](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.custommetadatatypes_limitations.htm&type=5)